# Difference between DOM event and Javascript Event

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Is there any difference in between the DOM events that  we write in HTML Code like `<button onclick="showData">Click</button>` and writing in Javascript like `querySelector(button).addEventListener(click,showData)`.

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: You can have more than one eventListener

Comment: `onclick=` must point to a global function (runs in the global scope)

Comment: both are same, on HTML you need to define on each element while in javascript you can select multiple element add bind the same event together.

Comment: Both will fail if you misspell (see "addEvenet"), but the second will give an error (while 'oncilck' won't give an error)

Comment: See also: [Why is onClick in HTML bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)